# How are objects created in C++?

Tags: c++

I know Java but don't have much knowledge of C++. I am trying to write a class for the first 3 statements in main function of the code at https://developers.google.com/v8/get_started.

First I have questions about how objects are created in C++. See the below code.

```
HandleScope handle_scope;
Persistent<Context> context = Context::New();
Context::Scope context_scope(context);
```

I think in C++ when you declare a variable of a class an instance of the class created at the point. You do not need to use new keyword like in Java. So the first statement would create an instance of HandleScope which will be stored in handle_scope. 
Now I do not understand how the second statement would work. With my knowledge the part before = will create a new Persistent object which can be referred by the variable context. Then Context::New() will create a new object and store it in context? Huh, I know I am wrong. But I simply dont get how it would work?

I am trying to write a C++ class for the above. Here is my attempt.

```
class MyClass {
private:
    HandleScope handle_scope;
    Persistent<Context> context;
    Context::Scope context_scope;

public:
    MyClass(); 
};

MyClass::MyClass()
{
    context = Context::New();
    context_scope = new Context::Scope(context);
}
```

Have I done the initialization properly?

EDIT: Reply to peachykeen (in comments) 
I did the following experimentation.

I wrote a Test class as below.
 Test
    {
    public:
        Test() {
        cout << "Test" << endl;
    }
    };

In the main function I wrote Test test; It outputs "Test" which means an object is created without using new keyword.

Comment: @peachykeen: noooooo, please don't ever say stuff like that. There are enough bad C++ programmers around without actively promoting bad practices. You do *not* need to litter your code with `new` in C++, and doing so is just *asking* for memory leaks (it's also a clear sign of a bad C++ programmer)

Comment: @jalf and how to use smart pointers without new? oO

Comment: yeah, not sure if you're serious. You definitely have to use new; even a static method or factory uses new internally, and smart pointers have to be given instances (which have to come from *somewhere*). You don't want to `new` things into raw pointers, sure, but you do need to construct them.

Comment: @peachykeen: who cares what they use *internally*. There is a huge difference between using a data structure which internally calls `new` and `delete` for you, and calling `new` and `delete` on an ad-hoc basis in your high level code. If I see a `delete` call outside of a RAII class, I know the code is broken. If I see a `new` call whose result isn't immediately passed to a smart pointer, I *suspect* that the code is broken. And if I see a lot of `new` calls, regardless of whether or not the results are passed to smart pointers, I know that the code is badly written

Comment: @ForEveR sure, `new` can be used occasionally, if you pass the result into a smart pointer. But often, you don't need to do either: often, you can create your objects on the stack, or copy them into, say, a `std::vector` if you need them stored on the heap. Often, you don't need *new* at all.

Comment: @peachykeen You can construct automatic variables without using new. And you *should* do so as often as possible. Some structures will require points at which point you should use smart ones, but there is no need to use pointer (smart or otherwise) for everything.

Comment: @jalf Given the context of the question, I assumed the OP needed to create objects off the stack and pass them to some sort of smart pointer (the `Persistent<>` class). Obviously you aren't going to `new` everything, but there's no mention here of whether these are local/stack, and the code suggests they are intended to persist (possibly meaning heap). If that's not the case, then you are correct.

Comment: sorry if I may sound harsh, but **why** are you asking something so basic about a programming language? It wouldn't be better if you go read a basic tutorial/guide/book/whatever on C++?

Comment: @Cracker In your experiment there, "Test" is not an object, it's a constant string literal baked into the executable('s data segment). Even if you were creating an object there, because it's for use locally, you don't need to `new` it. I may have misunderstood the question; there are two forms of construction and I assumed/addressed one of them.

Comment: @peachykeen I just went by what you said. You said that one "most certainly" does need to use `new` in C++, when in fact, it can and should very often be avoided. You said that Java and C++ are "similar" in how they create objects, which is not true, because in C++ you're typically suppposed to create your objects without using `new`, and you said that C++ requires you to destroy your objects explicitly, which is only true for badly written C++ code, which overuses `new`, and fails to use RAII. I don't know what you meant, but I had to post a warning to others who read your comment like I did

Comment: @akappa Because I am lazy! I am trying to use the V8 engine which is written in C++. I have good knowledge of C but since V8 is written in C++ I am just trying to see whether I will be able to use C++ instead of C quickly without any reading (since I have good knowledge of other OO languages such as Java and C#).

Comment: C++ is a dangerous language to use if you're too lazy to learn it. It's not "an OO language such as Java and C#", and treating it as such is going to lead to a lot of pain and misery. ;)

Comment: @jaif lol! Yes I understand its different from Java and C#. I had studied it long back. I was just lazy to read on it for being able to execute one program. I guess now I have got the quick start I wanted and I will study it in depth now :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are right, in C++, objects are created as soon as they're defined. You do not need to use the `new` keyword.

However, unlike in Java, objects can be created with different kinds of duration. Using `new` creates an object on the heap, with *dynamic* storage duration: the variable lives until you explicitly `delete` it. (And `new` returns a pointer to the created object, so that you can track it)

If you simply define an object, as in your first and third lines, then it is created with *automatic* storage duration: that is, the object exists until it goes out of scope.

This means that you can create objects inside a function, and be *guaranteed* that they'll be destroyed as soon as you leave the function -- regardless of *how* you leave the function. Whether you return, or throw an exception, all objects with automatic storage duration (created without using `new`) are guaranteed to be properly cleaned up.

This means that you should always avoid `new` whenever possible. If you have to use `new`, you should typically wrap the resulting pointer into a *smart pointer* class, an object created with automatic storage duration, so that it gets destroyed automatically). The smart pointer will then call `delete` on the new-allocated object automatically, ensuring, again, that you don't leak memory.

This distinction is a very powerful tool, which good C++ programmers need to understand well. It is a key to avoiding memory leaks, or more generally, resource leaks of all kinds, and it is, in some respects, more powerful than Java's garbage collector.

For example, say we wish to open a file, and then write some data to it. In C++, we can do it like this:

```
void foo() {
    std::ofstream file("foo.txt");
    doStuff(file); // call a function which does something with the file   
}
```

And because `file` was declared without using `new`, because it has *automatic storage duration*, we are *guaranteed* that it will have its destructor invoked when it goes out of scope, and it will be properly cleaned up -- that is, the stream will be flushed, and the file handle will be closed.

It doesn't matter if `doStuff` might throw an exception. *No matter how* we leave `foo`, `file` will be properly destroyed, so we don't need to mess about with `try`/`finally` like you would in Java. The class is *exception-safe* by itself, without requiring any additional effort from the user.

Try writing a similar snippet in Java, one which *guarantees* that even if `doStuff` throws an exception, the file will be immediately closed. It'll be much longer, and requires more care on the part of the user.

Comment: Excellent answer. I might point out that "new with smart pointers" is an acceptable approximation to the way Java objects work, but creating objects on the heap with `new` _without_ smart pointers and creating objects on the stack are two subjects you should be sure you understand, @Cracker, as they do not have equivalents in Java.

Answer (score 0):

This would be the equivalent class:

```
class MyClass {
private:
    HandleScope handle_scope;
    Persistent<Context> context;
    Context::Scope context_scope;

public:
    MyClass(); 
};

MyClass::MyClass()
: context(Context::New()),
  context_scope(context)
{
}
```

When you write a statement like this:

```
Persistent<Context> context = Context::New();
```

You are constructing context using the copy constructor.  This is different from creating the object and then assigning a new value, although the result might often be equivalent.

Likewise this statement:

```
Context::Scope context_scope(context);
```

is constructing context_scope and passing context to the constructor.  You get the equivalent behavior in a class using the constructor initializer syntax as in my example.

Answer (score 0):

```
Persistent<Context> context = Context::New();
```

create object of type `Persistent<Context>`, initialized from returned of Context::New, if c-tor is not explicit.

Simple example.

```
#include <iostream>

class C
{
public:
    C(int)
    {
        std::cout << "C::C(int)" << std::endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    C c = 1;
}
```

your class should be

```
class MyClass {
private:
    HandleScope handle_scope;
    Persistent<Context> context;
    Context::Scope context_scope;

public:
    MyClass(); 
};

MyClass::MyClass():context(Context::New()),
    context_scope(Context::Scope(context))
{
}
```

if Context::Scope is not pointer.

Answer (score 0):

To create an instance of an object, you need only this: `Type name;` **The `new`keyword creates a pointer to an object.** Normally, to initialize the object, we use parenthesis: `Type name(parameter);` Sometimes, when an object supports copying, you can use a function that returns an object and assign it to that object: `Type name = Some_function_that_returns_Type();` You can now use `name` like any other object. If you say `Type name = new Type;`, you will get a compiler error. **The keyword new returns a pointer.** It would be correct to say `Type * name = new Type;`. (Note the `*`, saying that it is a **pointer** to a `Type` class, named `name`. When I refer to `Type` it is any object, such as your HandleScope. When I refer to `name`, it is the new object you are creating. The all of all is this: **`new` is a completely different keyword that refers to pointers. If you are not using pointers, don't use it. Use the basic format `Type name(parameter, another_param);`.**